# Looking for an explanation for the code below on how to find the coordinates for cuboid?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I was able to come up with these codes below with sample input and output given in the question but I severely lack the concept behind this problem. Can someone please explain how this program works right from the beginning to end? like why do we use (x+1) and (y+1).. and so on thanks.

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
z = int(input())
n = int(input())

print([[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if (i+j+k) != n])
```

**Sample Input 0**

1
1
1
2

**Sample Output 0**

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]

Comment: You’re probably better off learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow is not meant to be a guide or tutorial.

Comment: Guide != guidance. _couldn’t get the logic as it’s purely mathematical._ That seems odd to me, purely mathematical in what sense?

Comment: This is the question I'm trying to solve "You are given three integers X, Y and Z  and  representing the dimensions of a cuboid along with an integer N . You have to print a list of all possible coordinates given by (i,j,k) on a 3D grid where the sum of i+j+k  is not equal to N."

Comment: Alright, and which part is problematic, exactly?

Comment: I just wanna know  how the print statement condition behaves "print([[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if (i+j+k) != n])" when the input x,y,z,n is given. It'd be nice if you can use the inputs (1 1 1 2) to explain the process. Just wanna let you know I have basic knowledge on for loops and if statements :)

Comment: Which part of it, though? Have you tried transforming it into a standard for loop? That might make things clearer.

Comment: Yeah I have tried it even with the code written on the book with standard for loop. Sill have hard time understanding it though. Which part of it? Maybe it'd be cool if can explain me the whole part. Can you try writing down the "comments" with "#" below the codes on how the logic works?  For instance x = int(input()) #getsinput from the user. That'd would be helpful

Comment: That’s what I meant when I wrote that _Stack Overflow is not meant to be a [complete] guide or tutorial_ You can find plenty of great resources to learn Python, and the documentation is quite good. _on the book with_ What book? If you have a book there should be some explanations in it, no?

Comment: @AMC It's pretty hard to look for list-comprehensions without knowing they are called list-comprehensions and it is a concept that is not present in other languages. I think his questions is legitimate.

Answer (score 1):

The list comprehension:

```
[[i,j,k] for i in range(x+1) for j in range(y+1) for k in range(z+1) if (i+j+k) != n]
```

Is more readable if you "unroll" it:

```
[
    [i,j,k]
    for i in range(x+1)
    for j in range(y+1)
    for k in range(z+1)
    if (i+j+k) != n
]
```

This is equivalent to the regular loop:

```
ret = []
for i in range(x+1): # 0, 1, ..., x
    for j in range(y+1): # 0, 1, ..., y
        for k in range(z+1): # 0, 1, ..., z
            if i+j+k != n:
                ret.append([i,j,k])
```

Basically, you keep every triplet in the cube `[0, x] * [0, y] * [0, z]` whose sum is not `n`.

The [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-range) function builds an immutable sequence. `range(stop)` is the sequence `0, 1, ..., stop-1`. Hence, `range(x+1)` is the sequence `0, 1, ..., x`. (Other parameters exist, see link.)

With `x, y, z, n = (1, 1, 1, 2)`, you have:

```
ret = []
for i in (0, 1): # 0, 1
    for j in (0, 1): # 0, 1
        for k in (0, 1): # 0, 1
            if i+j+k != 2:
                ret.append([i,j,k])
```

The triplets: `[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]` are tested, and `[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]` are removed, leaving `[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]`.

Comment: As he specifically asked for `x+1`, I would add a brief explanation on how `range`works. Tellinh him it iterates over the numbers starting at 0 and stoping one step before the provided input. Additionally there are other parameters that allow to specify the starting point and the step size.

Comment: @Adirio Done. Thanks!